# Connecting Standalone Flink Cluster on Azure VM with Azure Event Hub Kafka

Tags: java, azure, apache-kafka, apache-flink, azure-eventhub

I have created an Azure VM with Ubuntu OS, where I have installed Flink 1.16.1 with all its prerequisite. The VM is in a VNet.

At the other side I have an Azure Event Hub for Apache Kafka, which is public.

At the Vnet of the VM I have created Inbound and Outbound security rules for the 9093 port, in order to communicate with my event hub.

I have started a cluster at my ubuntu VM by using the following command at the terminal:

```
$FLINK_HOME/bin/start-cluster.sh
```

I have created a fat jar with mvn clean package and I deployed it to the Flink cluster by using the following command:

```
$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink run -d -c event-hub-kafka-consumer.jar
```

The Java code of the FlinkKafkaConsumer that I am trying to deploy is included below:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.enumerator.initializer.OffsetsInitializer;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.eventtime.WatermarkStrategy;

public class FlinkKafkaConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
            .setBootstrapServers("namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093")
            .setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")
            .setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"Endpoint=sb://namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=*********;SharedAccessKey=****************\";")
            .setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
            .setTopics("topicA")
            .setGroupId("flink-consumer")
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
            .build();

        DataStream<String> stream = env.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "KafkaSource");

        stream.print();
        env.execute("Testing flink consumer");
    }
}
```

It seems that, the Flink Job is been created, event hub receives the requests but then Flink receives 0 messages.

Is there any possible explanation to this?

**Note: Another consumer is subscribed to the same topic with a completely different group-id.**

Comment: 1) You've cut off ConsumerConfig from the logs 2) You've not set `auto.offset.reset=earliest`

Comment: First of all, thank you @OneCricketeer for the solution that you propose. Can you please elaborate what do you mean with the phrase "You've cut off ConsumerConfig from the logs"?

Comment: Did that solve the problem? Your question here only shows AdminClientConfig from Kafka logs, but there's more output, and the problem you're asking about is related to the consumer config

Comment: No this didn't solve my problem. If I include the rest of the output, my question exceeds the maximum allowed characters. The output above is produced at the Flink JobManger. I have posted from it what is related to the connection to Kafka. Do you want me to include anything else? What I haven't included at the main post is that another consumer is subscribed to the same topic but with a completely different group-id.

Comment: I am interested in seeing what you have as `auto.offset.reset` from the ConsumerConfig, as mentioned since any Kafka consumer defaults to start at the end of the topic, where there may be no data, if your producer is not active. The adminclient logs are unnecessary, so I suggested removing them

Comment: I found a way of running the Job. Instead of starting the cluster and then submitting the job from a .jar, I run the **mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="FlinkKafkaConsumer"** command. I assume that the main reason of not connecting is the runtime environment that is been set by the start-cluster.sh of Flink, when I start the cluster. I will investigate it further and I will come back with the answer.

Comment: You should be able to run the main class direct from your IDE without maven command, but yes, that is one way to run any Java class from Maven directly without a JAR file